# How to remove ? from the url using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url, seo

I having a URL http://www.domain.com/postname/?a_different_world

I need to change it to http://www.domain.com/postname/a_different_world

How to remove ?  from the URL using Htacccess(Wordpress)

I use following htaccess code. But it is not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php-$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /domain.com/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/postname/([0-9]+)$ /? $1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Please use `example.com` for your example domain, not `domain.com` (which is owned by someone, probably not being you).

Answer (score 1):

The rule match string strips out the query string (everything after the ?). Hence you want to drop the ? and explicitly use the query string like this (instead of your last rule)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([\w\-]+)$
RewriteRule ^postname/$ postname/%1?   [L]
```

Note that you should drop the leading / as this won't match as .htaccess rule match string drops the leading /; also note the ? in the replacement pattern and omission of the QSA flag as you *don't* want to append the query string.

Also move this rule above the previous cond/rule as this second rule will fire on your postname pattern so you'll never get to this rule unless you move it up one.